# Reducing priority of MySQL commands/jobs (add an index/other commands)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance

We have a moderately large production MySQL database. Periodically, we will run commands, usually via a rails migration, that while running, bog down the database.  As a specific example, we might add an index to a large table.

Is there any method that can reduce the priority MySQL gives to a specific task. A sort of "nice" within MySQL itself?  I found this, which is what inspired the question:
[PostgreSQL tips and tricks](http://www.gabrielweinberg.com/blog/2011/05/postgresql.html)

Since adding an index causes the work to be done within the DB and MySQL process, lowering the priority of the Rails migration process seems like it won't help. Are there other ways we can lower the priority?

Comment: What kind of commands are you running?

Comment: This is what maintenance windows are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use multiple, replicated database servers to make changes like this.

In our case, **db1** is the master, replicated to **db2**. (db1->db2).

Start by making the change to db2.  If things lock, replication will stall, but that's OK.

Move your traffic to db2.  Any remnant traffic going to db1 will replicate over, so you won't lose anything.

Once there's no traffic on db1, rebuild it as a slave of db2 (db2->db1).

That's the general idea and you get very little downtime and you don't have to pull an all-nighter!  We actually have three servers, so it's a little more complicated, but not much.

Good luck.

Comment: It looks like what I hoped for isn't possible, so I'm awarding the answer to you, as your suggestion looks like the way to go...

Comment: I believe that other storage engines (non-isam, non-innodb) promise to not lock tables when altering the schema.  I've always been hesitant to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do this: commands that alter the database structure don't have a priority option.

If your tables are MyISAM, you can try this:

- [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) to make a backup of the table
- import that backup it into a different database server (one that's not under load)
- make the changes *there*
- make a mysqlhotcopy backup of the altered table
- import it into the live server

Note that this may or may not be faster than adding the index on the live server, depending on the time it takes you to transfer the table back and forth.

Comment: This assumes that no data has changed in the table during the process.

Comment: @Alain Collins: That is an issue, yes; and can wreak havoc with FKs and whatnot. There are workarounds to resync the added-in-the-meantime rows, but (short of replication) I haven't been able to find a 100% safe workaround, except for `LOCK TABLE WRITE` - in which case, don't bother and just `ALTER TABLE` in-place.